# Building dynamic table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So my ultimate goal is for the user to input three or more words, and then I must
seperate the words, I.E if there are 4 words, I have to build 4 Rows with the word in each,
I have been at it for hours and just can't figure out why the insertRow() method wont work, its telling me that "cannot call insertRow() method of undefined"

what I have in the else section of my conditional:

```
//build table around input
    var table=document.getElementById('myTable');


    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
    table.insertRow(i);
    table.insertCell(i);}
```

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you call `.insertRow()` on the table DOM object, but then you need to call `.insertRow()` on a row, not on the table.  See [MDN on insertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell) for more details.  Here's an example of some working code:

```
function addWords(e) {

    var str = document.getElementById("words").value;
    var words = str.split(/[\s,]/);
    if (words.length && words[0]) {
        //build table around input
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable');

        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
            cell.innerHTML = words[i];
        }
    }
}
```

And a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3g3Qy/

Answer (score 0):

You should call insertCell on a Row object.

```
var row = table.insertRow();
row.insertCell();
```

Comment: Do you have a table with id=myTable?

Comment: If you're running this script just before table is added to the DOM, it won't be able to find the table.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `console.log(table)` after `var table=...`. If it prints undefined, the problem is that the script is running too soon and you'll need to move the script to the very bottom of the page, or [wait for the DOM to load](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded).